# Redis looking for env redis url variable not sure where to put env variable bad URI(is not URI?): (URI::InvalidURIError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am quite new to redis. This rails application has a redis.rb file in config/initializers

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
$redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

The redis url is on heroku config.

I can't just replace `REDIS_URL` with the `REDIS_URL` from heroku config.

I am getting a URI parse error

```
 bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

my question is where should I place the redis url ? where is it searching the env variable from?

Comment: Looks like you haven't configured your `ENV['REDIS_URL']` variable correctly, because it's passing `nil` to `URI.parse()`:

Comment: @MikeCampbell I assumed that it got set up correctly. I inherited the app from someone. Its nice to know that I need to double check.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you're getting this when doing rake. The problem is that when rake-ing, your environment variables aren't set, which leads to this error (info at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline). To overcome, use a conditional intializer instead, e.g.:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
    $redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end
```

P.S. alternatively, use [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) but note that according to Heroku:

> Using this labs feature is considered counter to Heroku best practices. 
>   This labs feature can make your builds less deterministic and require 
>   re-deploys after making config changes. Ideally your app should be able to 
>   build without config.