# Heroku with Sidekiq and Redis_To_Go

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

Trying to send emails with Sidekiq using Redis_To_Go, but my worker keeps crashing. I've done everything I could find, and I'm sure this is a small issue. Though I can't figure it out!

./Procfile.txt:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

./config/initializers/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis::Namespace.new("ihms_env_app", :redis => Redis.new)

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
```

I've scaled the workers from 0 to 1

```
$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: up 2014/05/08 10:46:56 (~ 7m ago)

=== worker (1X): `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
worker.1: crashed 2014/05/08 10:47:00 (~ 7m ago)
```

log

```
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
app[worker.1]: 
app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
```

in console, I've run

```
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.

Your output from `heroku ps` and the logs indicates that you're trying, and failing, to run a rake task called "jobs:work".

What happens when you run: `bundle exec rake jobs:work` in your local directory?  I'm going to guess it fails?

The `Procfile` you provide contradicts your logs.  It has `Sidekiq` and not `rake` as the command.  Are you sure you've checked it in to to your git repo and deployed it?

Comment: Yes, running that command in my local directory fails. I thought the same thing and tried to re-push up to the Heroku repository but was given 'Already up-to date'. I just added a space in procfile and resubmitted, restarted heroku and am still getting a crashed worker. Procfile.txt is directory root with .gitignore and gemfile correct?

Comment: Ah.  No.  You've named the Procfile incorrectly.  It should be named `Procfile` (see [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates)) - not `Procfile.txt`

Comment: I had just thought of that immediately after posting my comment. When the docs said "A Procfile is a text file named Procfile placed in the root of your application", I just made an assumption. Works now with the renamed file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a conditional initializer in your redis.rb file, such as:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
    $redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end
```

For more details, see my answer to [Redis looking for env redis url variable not sure where to put env variable bad URI(is not URI?): (URI::InvalidURIError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247982/redis-looking-for-env-redis-url-variable-not-sure-where-to-put-env-variable-bad/23249313#23249313)