# Redis tries to connect to localhost on Heroku instead of REDIS_URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I have a Rails app which uses Redis for background jobs. On Heroku I use the Heroku Redis add-on. When I deploy to Heroku, it gives me this error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379
```

It seems it tries to connect to localhost. I have both a `REDIS_URL` and `REDIS_PROVIDER` environment variable on Heroku. And this is how my `redis.rb` looks like:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
else
  uri = URI.parse("redis://localhost:6379")
end
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

And this is my `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=* COUNT=1
```

Any ideas why it is not working? Even if I change `redis.rb` so it only has the `REDIS_URL` as url, it gives the same error.

Update: added error trace:

```
remote:        Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:345:in `rescue in establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:331:in `establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `ensure_connected'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `logging'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:120:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:351:in `block in time'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:350:in `time'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:435:in `call_with_namespace'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:321:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:100:in `redis_time_available?'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:15:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque.rb:125:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque.rb:125:in `redis='
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-web-0.0.9/config/initializers/resque_config.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:6379
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:206:in `rescue in connect_addrinfo'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:198:in `connect_addrinfo'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:239:in `block in connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:237:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:237:in `each_with_index'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:237:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:313:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:336:in `establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `ensure_connected'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `logging'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:120:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:351:in `block in time'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:350:in `time'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:435:in `call_with_namespace'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:321:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:100:in `redis_time_available?'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:15:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque.rb:125:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque.rb:125:in `redis='
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-web-0.0.9/config/initializers/resque_config.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable: Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:199:in `connect_addrinfo'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:239:in `block in connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:237:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:237:in `each_with_index'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:237:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:313:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:336:in `establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `ensure_connected'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in `logging'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:120:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:351:in `block in time'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:350:in `time'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:435:in `call_with_namespace'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:321:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:100:in `redis_time_available?'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque/data_store.rb:15:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque.rb:125:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-1.27.2/lib/resque.rb:125:in `redis='
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-web-0.0.9/config/initializers/resque_config.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !     Attempted to access a nonexistent database:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pre-provision-database
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to backbone-app-staging.
remote: 
To git@heroku.com:backbone-app-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] rails5 -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:backbone-app-staging.git'
```

Comment: What `RAILS_ENV` is set to when you run `heroku config`?

Comment: That one was missing, but after adding that environment variable, it still returns the same error unfortunately. Silly thing is that I have another Rails app on Heroku with the exact same setup which is working...

Comment: @John do you really need to parse url? According to docs redis can receive  `url` parameter as config option: `Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])`

Comment: @Slava.K you mean replacing the entire `redis.rb` with `Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])`?

Comment: @John yes, can you try it?

Comment: I think it is always picking up the URL `"redis://localhost:6379"` due to `Rails.env.production?` is false. There is no way heroku can automatically generate URL like the one you specified. Please check what the environment is set to by running `heroku run rails c`, and then `Rails.env` in the console.

Comment: @31piy `Rails.env` returns `production`

Comment: What's the output for ```heroku config:get REDIS_URL``` ?

Comment: I'm curious to know what happens if you take the evaluation out of the picture. Don't check Rails.env.production.  Always connect to ENV["REDIS_URL"]

Comment: @ShaironToledo: it is `redis://h:p942xxxxx@ec999999.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:16369` (`xxx` and `999` not the real values of course)

Comment: Then check your resque config ...  Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'

Comment: Possible duplicate of this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247982/redis-looking-for-env-redis-url-variable-not-sure-where-to-put-env-variable-bad

Comment: Can you try migrating the same settings to a fresh new heroku app?

Comment: @31piy I have another Rails app on Heroku with the exact same settings and there is works fine.

Answer (score 12):

I can think of two possibilities:

- Is something setting `ENV['REDIS_URL']` before the initializer runs? For instance maybe you have a `.env` file checked into git that is overriding the Heroku variable?
- You say this code is from `redis.rb`. Do you have a `config/initializers/resque.rb` also? What about `config/resque.yml`? Either of those may be *also* trying to open a Redis connection. (If you could post the entire stack trace of your error, you could confirm this or rule it out.) Or are you using Redis for anything other than Resque?

You could also do some printf debugging and change your initializer to say:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  puts "production: #{ENV['REDIS_URL']}"
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
else
  puts "not production"
  uri = URI.parse("redis://localhost:6379")
end
```

That should help you clarify what's going on. (You may need to use `Rails.logger.info` instead of `puts`.)

**EDIT:** That stack trace is very helpful! Sure enough, your own initializer isn't in there at all, but there is other code trying to load its own redis connection, here:

```
remote:        /tmp/build_329306a238b046dda86a54d29db48f4c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/resque-web-0.0.9/config/initializers/resque_config.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

If you [look up that gem](https://github.com/resque/resque-web/blob/v0.0.9/config/initializers/resque_config.rb), you can see it is doing this:

```
require 'resque'

config = ENV.fetch("RAILS_RESQUE_REDIS", "127.0.0.1:6379")
Resque.redis = config
```

So I think the answer is to set `RAILS_RESQUE_REDIS` *in addition* to `REDIS_URL`. You can use the Heroku `config:set` command to do that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions, I have added the error trace. There is no `config/initializers/resque.rb` and also no `config/resque.yml`, just a `config/initializers/redis.rb`.

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver! I was having the exact same issue, and setting `RAILS_RESQUE_REDIS` fixed it for me, but someone needs to file this issue with heroku. It seems to be a pretty recent bug.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to pass the USERNAME to the connector, and your REDIS_URL can have been changed by the service provider...

I recommend use

```
$redis = if Rails.env.production? ? Redis.new(ENV["REDIS_URL"]) : Redis.new("redis://localhost:6379")
```

It would be even better use the env variable your service provider set, like `ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']`, because if they change the url for any motive, like when you update a plan or they need to change their infra... they could just set their variable and it would be transparent for you, without any interruption of service.

If you maintain yourself the `REDIS_URL`, and they change their url, your app will lost access to until you figure out the URL should change and set the update the `REDIS_URL` again

**OBS**

If the problem is when setting up the worker... the problem can be even that it is not starting with the correct environment, at least if you run it on Rails 5, you should config your resque Rakefile to

```
#If you're using Rails 5.x, include the following in lib/tasks/resque.rb:

require 'resque/tasks'
task 'resque:setup' => :environment
```

Comment: I'm using Heroku Redis and their env variable is `ENV["REDIS_URL"]`, so that should be OK. I made the changes, but still returns the same error.

Comment: Can you paste the trace produced by that error? And are you sure this script are being run? If you place a `Rails.logger.info "TRY TO CONFIG THINGS"` at the beginning of this script that text appears on the log?

Answer (score 4):

Inside of your `config/initializes/set_redis_url.rb`

```
ENV['REDIS_URL'] = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"] if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
```

In my past i have used action cable to work with redis and my app wouldn't work without these lines in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://your-app.herokuapp.com',
                                           'http://your-app.herokuapp.com']

config.action_cable.url = "wss://sitepoint-custom-messaging.herokuapp.com/cable"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Redis to go`  addon on Heroku

replace this line. 
 `URI.parse("redis://localhost:6379")`
with

You get the Redis link from REDISTOGO_URL in settings and `Config Vars` on heroku

```
URI.parse("redis://redistogo:72adffd1a5bf8ffdffddfdafdfdfdaferjaw.redistogo.com:10289")
```

for Rails 6 ~>
you would do this

```
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://redistogo:72adffd1a5bf8fe74a2c05fdfdafdfreefdfaderjaw.redistogo.com:12317/" } %>
```

> These are dummy links