# Redis redirects to localhost on Heroku (Rails 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an app hosted on Heroku, using Redis Cloud and ActionCable. Locally everything works but on Heroku the user is redirected to a localhost address after a form is submitted. I have tried most of the advice listed here (apart from resque settings since resque gem is not installed): [Redis tries to connect to localhost on Heroku instead of REDIS_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388458/redis-tries-to-connect-to-localhost-on-heroku-instead-of-redis-url)

Redis Cloud was added with

```
heroku addons:create rediscloud:30
```

This is in my cable.yml, I have commented out two other solutions that I tried that also did not work (in my actual code, redis url is set to the actual address rather than xxx999)

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  # url: <%= ENV.fetch('REDISCLOUD_URL') %>
  # url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://default:xxx999@redis-13674.c77.eu-west-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13674" } %>
  channel_prefix: art--collabs_production
```

In redis.rb:

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
  $redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
end
```

In production.rb I have the following (again, the commented out code has been tried and also failed)

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://www.artcollabs.net/cable"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ "http://www.artcollabs.net", "https://www.artcollabs.net" ]

# config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/1") }
config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL", "redis://default:xxx999@redis-13674.c77.eu-west-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13674") }
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Why not use `heroku config:set REDISCLOUD_URL=redis://default:xxx999@redis-13674.c77.eu-west-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13674` instead of hardcoding the URL as a default in your configuration files?

Comment: It is already set to this address in heroku config. The only reason I hardcoded it is because using `redis://localhost:6379/1` or `redis://localhost:6379/0` in its place did not work

Comment: If you have set `ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']` then your default will never be used. Thats how defaults work.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it still redirects to localhost?

Comment: What does `heroku config:get REDISCLOUD_URL` tell you?

Comment: It gives me the same address that I hardcoded